# IF Function not working

Tags: microsoft-excel

`=IFS(F5<TIME(19,59,59),"0",F5>TIME(19,59,59),"100",F5>TIME(21,59,59),"200")`

Condition 1 - Monday to Friday if Employee work After 19:59 clock then he will get Rs100

Condition 2 - Monday to Friday if Employee work After 21:59 clock then he will get Rsw00

Condition 3 - During Saturday Sunday Employee work more than 4 hours 59 mins to 7 hours 59 Mins then he will get Rs 300.

Condition 4 - During Saturday Sunday Employee work more than 7 hours 59 Mins then he will get Rs 500.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question and add some sample data to show what exactly is not working right now.

Comment: Your formula doesn't take into account the day of the week, nor any duration of work.  Only conditions 1 & 2 may be handled.

Comment: Did you check if the cell format is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your second `ifs` section needs to be modified (the way it is currently written if your second check is true it will never get to the third check). You can either check  `F5>TIME(21,59,59)` or `F5<TIME(21,59,59)`. Depending which check you choose, the final check will be different. Regardless of which way you pick, technically, you don't have to do your last check, because if the first two checks fails, then your last section has to be true. So you can do this instead:

```
=IFS(F5<TIME(19,59,59),"0",F5>TIME(21,59,59),"200",TRUE,"100")
```

or alternatively

```
=IFS(F5<TIME(19,59,59),"0",F5<TIME(21,59,59),"100",TRUE,"200")
```

Please note that by using quotations around your values `"100"` you are creating a text value, and not a number, so this cannot be directly added.

As for condition 3 and 4, you'll need to provide more detail, as we don't know if those "premiums" are additive (you work Sunday for 8 hours and after 21:59:59 do you get 200 + 500 = 700 or do you get only 500). I think once you figure this part out you can fix it yourself.